# Upload picture using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

When I try to login, I am able to authenticate properly. However, when I try and upload a picture, I get an error saying: "Invalid application ID". I know that I copied/pasted the application ID properly so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
public void uploadFacebookPhoto(String path,String description)
{
    byte[] data = null;

    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putByteArray("picture", data);
    //params.putString("description", description);

    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
}
```

Edit: Here's the output from the logcat

> Response: {"error_code":101,"error_msg":"Invalid application
>   ID.","request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"photos.upload"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}

Comment: first you check your session is valid or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't add the following to onActivityResult()

```
mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```